# How can I validate Android edittext for accepting string and integer

Tags: android

What is the validation expression for string(space)integer? I want to enter the data in the format of "month date"(eg.March 22) in database.

Comment: write your own regex. https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar could help

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll help you

```
String abc = "March 2";
String[] split = abc.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
sb.append(split[i]);
if (i != split.length - 1) {
    sb.append(" ");
}
}
String combined = sb.toString();
```

At 0 position you'll get your months then get into a `String` and matches with your static array.

And at 1 position, you'll get your date, you can match it too.

Comment: i need the expression for string+integer not the exact date format

Comment: sorry am a beginner in android,i have a calender application and it allows the user to add events and the date of events in the format "month name  date" (March 12) .

Comment: Without adding space or comma, it's not easy to match the `String`

Comment: You should validate `editText` like that "Add space between months and date and show it in hint of EditText " too.